# How to send data via ajax post, using arrays

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have this array called sendData, which has index sendData [0] [1] [2].....

now

```
sendData[0]="name="+variable+"&class="+variable;
sendData[1]="name="+variable+"&class="+variable;
sendData[2]="name="+variable+"&class="+variable;
```

Now how do I send the whole sendData ?

Comment: I am attempting to help you. Can you use JQuery and what does your html form look like now?

Answer (score 1):

If jQuery is allowed then you can try the following:

```
$.ajax({
        url:"Your URL", 
        type: "post",
        data: {'data' : JSON.stringify(sendData)},
        success: function (response) {
          console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
           console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
        }
    });
```

Comment: oh that didnt work at all... sorry... I posted the code that worked ... thnxxxxxxx alot ....

Answer (score 0):

```
var sendData=new Object();
for(i=0;i<numberOfRows;i++){  //Number of rows
sendData[i]=new Object; 
for(var key in return_data_columns_detail[0]){    //contains the json data for column headers
var id="ip"+cnt+"addRow"+addIpRow;  //HTML ID for input fields contained inside table rows
var data=document.getElementById(id).value;
sendData[i][return_data_columns_detail[0][key]]=data;
cnt++;
}
addIpRow++
}


$.ajax({
    url:"../include/handle_event_add_team.php",
    type:"POST",
    data:sendData,
    dataType:"json",
    success:function(){
        console.log("after add button click team");
        ajax_post_display_table();
        //display_table_team();
    }
});

ok here is how i did it by creating an object which can me parsed into json data and sending to php server
```